# Как изменить url в поиске и задать параметры

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть несколько моделей:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :material
  belongs_to :color
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :products
end

class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :products
end
```

Допустим выбрали по 1 параметру в каждом:

```
material: 'wood'
color:    'gray'
```

Нужно найти все products с такими значиниями.
А теперь самое интересное, нужно чтобы урл был не `site.com/search?utf8=✓&..wood..gray`, а `site.com/wood/gray`, и была возможность ставить сеошные `title`, `description` и `keywords`.

Слышал что можно как то создать модель для пересечений, но так и не понял.

Answer (score 1):

1. В `routes.rb`:

   ```
   get "(:material)/(:color)", to: "search#index", as: :search
   # search и index - твои контроллер и экшн соответственно.
   ```
2. В `SearchController`:

   ```
   @products = 
     Product.where(
       color: Color.where(slug: params[:color])
       material: Material.where(slug: params[:material])
     )
   ```

Минус такого подхода в том, что нельзя использовать множественный выбор для материала и цвета. Роуты просто не пропустят.

И ещё, чтобы переходить на такие красивые урлы из формы поиска будет нужно колдовать с JS перед сабмитом, либо делать редирект.

Но обычно с этим не заморачиваются. Для поисковиков оставляют красивые урлы, а пользователей отправляют через `search?...`. И на страницы добавляют `link canonical`.

**UPD:**

> А как установить сео title description keywords на результат поиска?

Нужно где-то их сформровать и потом просто добавить в лайоут.
Например в том же `SearchController`:

```
def seo_data
  @color = Color.find_by(slug: params[:color])
  @material = Material.find_by(slug: params[:material])
end
```

А потом в `app/views/layouts/<your-layout>` добавить куда нужно вывод этих тэгов. Например так:

```
<title>Диваны <%= @color.name %>, <%= @material.name %> купить, без смс. Без регистрации. Online.</title>
```

Comment: А как установить сео title description keywords на результат поиска?